# JavaScript Framework for Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am working with Google Maps API v3 in JavaScript.

Using it "in raw" is *low-level* somehow.

I am wondering if simple and robust **framework** over this API exists.

Comment: http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/

Comment: @putvande Nice link. Could you please post it with some description as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/ Is a fairly simple Framework or Plugin to draw a map. All you need is a few lines of code.

```
var map;
$(document).ready(function () {
    map = new GMaps({
        div: '#map',
        lat: -12.043333,
        lng: -77.028333
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

And some CSS :

```
#map { width: 800px; height: 600px; }
```

And make sure you include [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com), [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true) and the [gMap](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/) itself (Google Maps and jQuery needs to be there before gMap otherwise you will get an error.)

See [a Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HzN73/)

See [more examples](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples.html)

I hope it helps, if not, let me know.

Comment: Looks like it is definitely a thing I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Mapabstraction - is available but the benefits it brings are being able to swap providors not less complex I am afraid.

http://mapstraction.com/

Maybe worth a look though

Answer (score 0):

There are Frameworks. 
Try [google](https://www.google.de/search?q=javasiprt%20maps%20api%20jquery&oq=javasiprt%20maps%20api%20jquery&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.6484j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=122&espv=210&q=javascript%20maps%20api%20jquery&spell=1) :-)

I have no experiences with any of those frameworks. For some cases it will make sense I think.
But when you get in deep complex things the Maps Api from google is great and I think you will need no Framework.